# Windows Phone 7 IE - Get GPS Coordinates From Mobisite

Tags: windows-phone-7

I use the following code to get the GPS coordinates on a Android/iOS device from a mobisite but it doesn't work on WP7.

How can I get a user's GPS coordinates in IE on a WP7 device? (I am testing on a Samsung Omnia 7).

```
<script language="javascript">
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(findLocation, noLocation);

    function findLocation(position)
    {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Lat: " + lat + ", Long: " + lng;
    }

    function noLocation()
    {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Unable to get location";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you run this on a WP7 device?

When are you running this? Be sure to do it after the document has loaded.

If you're running this inside a WebBrowser control then be sure to set [IsGeolocationEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.isgeolocationenabled%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to true.

ALso check that location is enabled on the device and in IE.

X-Ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg593067.aspx
The error callback should contain a positionError parameter which may give you more information about any error.

Comment: I've tried the sample code on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg593067.aspx but getting "Geolocation not supported" so not sure whats wrong there.

Comment: Are you running the Windows Phone 7.1 RC version of the SDK? IE7 probably don't support it, so you need Mango (with IE9) on either the phone or the emulator.

Comment: Am doing this on the actual phone itself... A Samsung Omnia 7 running WP7 (Not Mango).